# rows_update : How to handle the error of this function when there are duplicates?

Tags: r, dataframe, error-handling, row, modifier

When using rows_update for the following two dataframes

```
df1 = data.frame(ID = c(1,rep(2,5),7:10), Num = c(111,rep(15,5),112:115))

g1 = data.frame(ID = rep(2,5), Num = rep(16,5))

rows_update(df1 , g1 )
```

the output is

```
Matching, by = "ID"
Error in `rows_update()`:
! `y` key values must be unique.
ℹ The following rows contain duplicate key values: `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::rows_update(df1, g1)
 2. dplyr:::rows_update.data.frame(df1, g1)
```

How can I handle such error ? Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please add the answer to the answers section ?

Answer (score 2):

Since your list of updates basically just contains duplicate rows, you can make the `rows_update` function by simply removing duplicates. This will work

```
rows_update(df1 , unique(g1) )
#    ID Num
# 1   1 111
# 2   2  16
# 3   2  16
# 4   2  16
# 5   2  16
# 6   2  16
# 7   7 112
# 8   8 113
# 9   9 114
# 10 10 115
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
rows_update(df1, distinct(g1))
```

-output

```
 ID Num
1   1 111
2   2  16
3   2  16
4   2  16
5   2  16
6   2  16
7   7 112
8   8 113
9   9 114
10 10 115
```